# An app allowing to create dynamic urls based on given taxonomy and .csv file

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views, django-urls

Welcome.

Toodays problem is quiete complex and I need an advice or even guidance. So not to stall too long I'll try to describe my problem as accruate as it will be possible, with preserving as much details as it's possible.

I'm using `Django 1.8.1` and `Python 2.7` with some external packages.

So, from the beggining. I want to create a generic and universal draft of service, which could be used in dozens of diffrent ways. Setting it many times in many spots is a topic for other time. The idea of all this mess  always would be the same - deploy instance, upload file with taxonomy, create urls - magic happens, everything works.

Explanation:

User will be able to upload a `.csv` file, which will contain couple of very important fields. They shall be responsible for creating taxonomy for my addressation at my website.
Let's say I need to set up a website for shopping centers (at that particular time). And my taxonomy describes django how to create urls that would look somehow like this:

`gallery-name.my_website_address.com/shop/specific-product/`

As we can see thats not anything hard to code that up, but the problem starts when I would like to start up with a new website with a new taxonomy, let's say this time for list of lawyers, e.g. it might look like this:

`country.my_website_address.com/city/street/law-firm/lawyer/`

I think now you might start to feel where I'm heading with this idea. The main problem is how to approach it in a way to keep versatility and easines in deploying new applications with new taxonomy with new urls settings. How do I create urls dynamically, is it even possible to create urls dynamically for all solutions ? How can I connect my newly created urls from my .csv file, to my views ?

As I'm going deeper in this problem I'm starting notice some solutions.
I think it could be accomplished. For example when we look at this link:

`country.my_website_address.com/city/street/hospital/doctor`

First thing we see - subdomain, it can be set in django panel admin. Next, the domain, we don't care about that now, and then sublink - I noticed that they can be served by one view (except that last element). : `/city/street/hospital/` these can be always groupped in one spot. They will always look the same, it's a listing with a position on a map.

And the last element in our url the `doctor`, `lawyer`, `product`, `car` or something else, will always be displayed in the same way. Only details about it, provided by .csv file. I think I'll try to code it in a way which will allow me to pick which item from my file is a) subdomain b) listings c) specific item

So to sum up do you have any ideas how to make it all work ? How to create urls with keeping the connection to views, keeping the versatility ?

I'm buying beers for people who are willing to just share thoughts.

Best wishes !

Sebastian Burzyński

Comment: My initial thoughts are, with all respect, that I would recommend you to break down your issues to small specific ones and show some progress on your behalf. It seems that all of it is feasible to me, but as it is it is huge and this is not the place to get a full design for a new application.

Comment: I'm not trying to make any of you to design my app. I just need some ideas, and thoughts how this can be achived.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but I'm pretty sure Django's URL conf can take care of this for you.

At the end of the day,  Django compares patterns using Regular expressions:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'shop/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', views.shop_view),
    url(r'([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/', views.listing)
]
```

`views.listing` should get `(city,street,company,occupation)` as the input parameters.

---

#### EDIT: Fine, I think I get what you're looking for.

```
with open("csv.csv","r") as fp:
    taxonomy = ['/'.join(line.split(',')) for line in fp.readlines()]
urlpatterns = [url("(" + t + ")",views.split) for t in taxonomy]
```

where `split` will look like

```
def split(request, string):
    taxonomy = string.split('/')
```

*(I haven't tried this but it should work)*

Comment: Yes I know this is possible. I know how this can be done in the way u described. But this is hard coded. I want my URL's to be created dynamically with not stopping point, based on my file uploaded.

Comment: Can you give a few sample lines from your CSV?

Comment: I don't think you get it. There will be dozens of files. With diffrent taxonomy.

Comment: Right. So, for the example taxonomy: `city/street/hospital/doctor`, etc. what does the csv file look like? and for a different example taxonomy, what does the csv file look like?

At the moment, your question doesn't give many details.

Comment: city/street/hospital/doctor

For this csv looks like:
new york; some street; some hospistal; name of doctor; 10000 other fields

for another taxonomy let's say 
gallery-name.my_website_address.com/shop/specific-product/

it looks like this:

gallery name; shop name; product  name

thats all, in admin panel im going to select which of those are listings subdomains or detailed objects

Comment: check my modification to the answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Ok this is usable, but the thing is I need to have every single suburl linked to a view. I know I can create one super long single url which runs one view. But the thing is I need to be able to access lets say the list of hospitals like this: berlin.example/some_street/ and nit should list me all hospitals in berlin in that specific street. For which I dont't have written url

Comment: bleh. that you can do once you have the `taxonomy` list.